# Iteration through a 2d javascript array in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that stores teams :

structure is like this :

```
leauges = new array( 
   array(juventus)
   array(milan)
   array(inter));
```

I want to iterate through the array to produce a fixture list and display like this :

HOME        AWAY

JUVENTUS VS  MILAN

JUVENTUS VS  INTER

MILAN    VS  INTER

MILAN    VS  JUVENTUS

INTER    VS  JUVENTUS

INTER    VS  MILAN

My approach has been to

1) create 2 for loops iterate from different ends of the array. 
2) In the loop test for a match between the teams to avoid a team playing itself
3) If not a match then place the team into a table next to each other.

my code is as follows :

```
 function makeFixture(){
 var thirdtab = $('#demo2');
var tableStart1 = "<table><TR><th>HOME</th><th>VS</th><th>AWAY</th></TR>"
var tableEnd1 = "</table>"
var tableMid1 = '' ;




tableMid1 += "<tr>";
for(i = 0; i < league.length; i++ ){
for(q = league.length; q > 0; j-- ){

if(q != i){
tableMid1 += "<tr><td>" + league[i][0] + " </td><td>" + league[q][0] 

+ "      </td></tr>" ;
}
}
}
thirdtab.html(tableStart1 + tableMid1 + tableEnd1);
}
```

In my console I get "league{}.0  null or not an object. 
If i take out the decrementing for loop I can get the home games as expected. I think this is where the problems lies.

Any help is really appreciated. Also I would prefer the best approach so if I am just simply doing this the wrong way a point in the right direction would be great

Comment: change your inner for loop to `for(q = league.length-1; q >= 0; q--)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break down the solution. Iterating through an array is easy right?

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
} // a b c d
```

Now lets go backwards by switching the direction of the indicies

```
for (var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
} // d c b a
```

The same logic works for 2d arrays

```
var matrix = [
    ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
    ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
    ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']];

for (var i = matrix.length-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) { // rows
    for (var j = matrix[i].length-1; j >= 0; j -= 1) { // cols
        console.log(matrix[i][j]); // pretend it doesnt print \n
    }
    console.log('\n');
}
// c3 c2 c1
// b3 b2 b1
// a3 a2 a1
```

The only tricky thing about going backwards through arrays is the iteration logic

instead of

```
for (var i = 0; i < upper_bound; i += 1) { /* ... */ }
```

We have

```
for (var i = upper_bound - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: It works perfectly. But something is not sticking. If the upper bound is 50. In child talk are you saying I = 49 while I is greater than or equal to 0 - 1 and execute code. Why did mine without the -1 on league.length turn up null? Thanks for the anwser

Comment: if your array has 50 things in it you want to go from `for (var i = 49; i >= 0; i -= 1) {}` this is because we are doing things starting at zero after we handle the zeroith element we will decrement i once more it will be -1 and we will not continue the loop.

Comment: @FintanCreaven so `var upper_bound = 50` we have `for (var i = upper_bound - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) { /* ... */ }` which is `i = 49; i >= 0`